# Docker FATA[0000] on Mac

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I have following error when I try to use docker on my Mac:

```
FATA[0000] Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.17/version: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

It doesn't matter if I use `sudo` or not... It doesn't matter which docker command I use or if I use `brew` or `boot2docker` to install it...

What should I do to resolve this issue ?

Comment: does `/var/run/docker.sock` exist? If not you need to create that directory!

Comment: Hi @JarrodRoberson, `/var/run/` exists, but not there's no sock file there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Docker daemon does not run natively on a Mac. Until it does, there will never be a socket for communicating with the daemon at `/var/run/`. You must therefore use TCP to communicate with the daemon because the daemon must be running on another machine (or a VM). Unix sockets only talk to processes running on the local machine. The unix socket method is very secure since it is only on the local machine and you must be root (or in the docker group) to talk with this socket.

### Insecure (but easy) TCP Client-Server Communications

You can run the Docker Engine in a very insecure way by setting some environment variables on the client end and starting your daemon in an insecure way on the daemon end:

```
Client: substitute the machine's host IP and port
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://host:2375
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=0

Daemon
docker -d -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
```

(see also https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#daemon-socket-option)

### Secure TCP Communications

Since you probably don't want random people talking to your docker daemon over the internet, you should run with TLS enabled. That's complicated, but all the steps are listed [in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/articles/https/). `boot2docker` and `kitematic` on Macs hides this complexity by setting up the TLS certificates for you and setting the environment variables needed to find the daemon.